# Spring bean created but not autowired

Tags: java, spring, testng, spring-jdbc

I am trying to run TestNG tests for DAO class in Spring. But DataSource reference is not autowired despite of the annotation. Here is part of the test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml"})
public class ToDoDaoImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    // Construction of this object fails
    private ToDoItemDaoImpl toDoDao;
}
```

Here is my Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- DataSource to be injected -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="DROPS">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db.create.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.myapp"/>
```

DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class ToDoItemDaoImpl implements ToDoItemDao {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert insert;

    public ToDoItemDaoImpl() {
        // dataSource is null here
        insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("toDoItem").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    // This method is not called by Spring
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
```

Here is stacktrace of the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.myapp.dao.ToDoItemDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1004)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:165)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.<init>(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert.<init>(SimpleJdbcInsert.java:60)
    at org.myapp.dao.ToDoItemDaoImpl.<init>(ToDoItemDaoImpl.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 52 more
null
```

Part of the log that shows that dataSource is created:

```
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'dataSource' to allow for resolving potential circular references
INFO  - DriverManagerDataSource    - Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0'
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0'
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
```

This is confuses me. The dataSource object is created, but is not Autowired into a Spring-managed object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is here

```
public ToDoItemDaoImpl() {
    // dataSource is null here
    insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("toDoItem").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
}
```

Spring can only autowire fields after the object has been created. That happens after the constructor is finished.

Spring will use reflection, ie. something like `Class.forName(yourClass).newInstance()`, to create your bean and then again use reflection to set each property.

However, in your constructor, the field is still `null` as that is the default value for all uninitialized fields of reference types.

One solution is to leave the constructor empty and add a [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotated method

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("toDoItem").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
}
```

Another solution is to add that initialization inside the `setDataSource()` method.

Comment: This "@Autowired is null" question is a gold mine, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @kryger It fills up my quotas.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Sotirios suggested above, you can also use Spring's contructor-args dependency injection to initialize the dataSource. So you can modify the constructor to be:

```
public ToDoItemDaoImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("toDoItem").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    }
```

Then you also need to add the following lines in the bean configuration file:

```
<bean id="toDoItemDaoImpl" class="mypackage.ToDoItemDaoImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```